# Add Resource in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resources

I tried searching how to add Resources in code behind. Need to add the following in code behind

```
 <DockManager:XamDockManager.Resources>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DockManager:DockManagerBrushKeys.TabbedListActiveTextFillKey}" Color="Green"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DockManager:DockManagerBrushKeys.TabbedListNotActiveTextFillKey}" Color="Pink"/>


        </DockManager:XamDockManager.Resources>
```

The Dockmanager is created in the code behind

Thanks

Comment: Why not just create the DockManager in the XAML?

Comment: The UI is generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var foo = new Foo();
XamDockManager dm = new XamDockManager...
dm.Resources.Add("foo", foo);
```

See also here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752326.aspx